# Inserting into table from dropdown using data from another table with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, dropdown

I have two tables, Parent and child in my MySQL database. I want to make a dropdown list in my child form in Laravel so I can select  a parent that already exist in my database table and I want it to be added in the child table as well. Help me please

Comment: can you show us some code.

Comment: I just created the child's form and inserted data, I didn't know how to make the dropdown part.

Comment: @Jane  write query $parents = Parrent::all() in controller and pass $parents to views and access it using foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked a question without any code, I believe you are only looking for a right nudge so here you go.

1. First of all, you will need to make one foreign key inside your child table for your parent table. That way parent and child tables will be connected.
2. Then from Controller, pass all parent ids/name pair when loading blade of child form and then loop through that data and make a dropdown with value as parent id and label as parent name, that way you can catch the parent id easily of the selected dropdown.
3. Next just save the data with the foreign key as the selected parent id inside your child table.